# Resolving a class overshadowed by a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I'm using Netbeans to develop my projects, I recently found a class in a jar file overshadows another file with the same name, how to solve this problem?

I have a project called DB_Tools_Panel, it has the following structure:

```
src/ : DB_Tools_Panel.java
       Utility/ : Tools_Lib.java
```

So inside src dir there is a file : DB_Tools_Panel.java, and also in the src dir there is a dir called Utility, inside Utility there is a file called Tools_Lib.java.

I packaged this project into a jar file: DB_Tools_Panel.jar

Then I created a 2nd project Fit, which has the following structure:

```
src/ : Fit.java
       Utility/ : Tools_Lib.java
lib/ : DB_Tools_Panel.jar
```

It uses DB_Tools_Panel.jar, so DB_Tools_Panel.jar is in Fit's lib dir, but now when I change the Tools_Lib.java in Fit/src/Utility, and run it, nothing will happen, as if it's never changed, now I know why, because JVM only runs the Tools_Lib.java from the package DB_Tools_Panel.jar, it won't see the Tools_Lib.java in Fit/src/Utility, in other words, after I included DB_Tools_Panel.jar into Fit project, the Tools_Lib.java in DB_Tools_Panel.jar will overshadow the Tools_Lib.java in Fit/src/Utility.

The Tools_Lib.java in both places are the same file, but the one in Fit/src/Utility might be more advanced, there are times when I test DB_Tools_Panel and make sure it works fine and package it into a jar file, and use it in other projects, and the Utility/Tools_Lib.java is used in later projects and needs improvements, but I don't necessarily want to always go back to DB_Tools_Panel.jar and update the Tools_Lib.java in it.

So my questions are:

[1] In this case is it possible to have 2 different Tools_Lib.java files in the Fit project, one in Fit/src/Utility/, the other in Fit/lib/DB_Tools_Panel.jar and not cause a conflict, what I mean by that is : when Fit calls Tools_Lib.java the one in it's src/Utility/ will be used and when some method in Fit calls DB_Tools_Panel, DB_Tools_Panel's Tools_Lib.java will be used inside DB_Tools_Panel's methods.

[2] Why is the Tools_Lib.java in DB_Tools_Panel.jar overshadowing the Tools_Lib.java in Fit/src/Utility?

[3] How to have the 2 Tools_Lib.java's be different and still be able to change the one in 
Fit/src/Utility and use it in the Fit project as if the one in DB_Tools_Panel.jar doesn't exist?

Comment: Why on earth do you give them the same name? Using proper packages for both classes, you may have a multitude of Tool_Lib's. Better yet: give them more meaningful names!

Comment: The search order determines the search order.  A jar is never in the exact same slot in the search order as a directory containing class files -- one must be ahead of the other.  Figure out your search order.  But note that you cannot load two classes of the same name at the same time without using separate class loaders (and then it's hard to reference both at the same time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using packages to allow easier identification of your projects / files. Additionally use more descriptive names instead of repeating names if possible.

For your class names you shouldn't be using `_`. It goes against [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411):

With all that, you could make your Projects look like this:

```
src/ : com/frank/db/tools/DBToolsPanel.java
       com/frank/db/tools/utility/ : ToolsLib.java
```

And this:

```
src/ : com/frank/fit/Fit.java
       com/frank/fit/utility/ : ToolsLib.java
lib/ : DBToolsPanel.jar
```

That way in `DBToolsPanel.java` your import would be `com.frank.db.tools.utility.ToolsLib` and `Fit.java` would have `com.frank.fit.utility.ToolsLib`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use different names.
2. If you can't use different names, put those two classes into two different packages.
3. If you can't put them into two different packages, because you need to use two different versions of the same library in the same project, then you have two possibilities to avoid the conflict:
   a) use two different ClassLoaders
   b) use shading to move one class to another package (there is a maven plugin for doing this at compile time)